# Pivot on CTE Description

Tags: sql-server

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

This is the result of a CTE query on multiple tables. I require to redefine the output and I can only think of using a pivot to do it.

```
    Id | Parent_Id | Description | Account_Number | Year_of_Entry | Amount
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    1  | NULL      | V           | 001            | 2017          | 4
    2  |  1        | W           | 002            | 2017          | 2
    3  |  2        | X           | 003            | 2017          | 1
    4  |  2        | Y           | 004            | 2017          | 1
    5  |  1        | Z           | 005            | 2017          | 2
    6  |  5        | T           | 006            | 2017          | 2
    7  |  6        | X           | 007            | 2017          | 1
    8  |  6        | Y           | 008            | 2017          | 1
    1  | NULL      | V           | 001            | 2016          | 8
    2  |  1        | W           | 002            | 2016          | 4
    3  |  2        | X           | 003            | 2016          | 2
    4  |  2        | Y           | 004            | 2016          | 2
    5  |  1        | Z           | 005            | 2016          | 4
    6  |  5        | X           | 006            | 2016          | 2
    7  |  5        | Y           | 007            | 2016          | 2
```

I would like to get an output that matches this one.

```
    Id | Parent_Id | Description | Account_Number | Year_of_entry| Amount|  X |  Y  
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1  | NULL      | V           | 001            | 2017         | 4     | 2  |  2  
    2  |  1        | W           | 002            | 2017         | 2     | 1  |  1
    5  |  1        | Z           | 005            | 2017         | 2     | 1  |  1
    6  |  5        | T           | 006            | 2017         | 2     | 1  |  1
    1  | NULL      | V           | 001            | 2016         | 8     | 4  |  4  
    2  |  1        | W           | 002            | 2016         | 4     | 2  |  2
    5  |  1        | Z           | 005            | 2016         | 4     | 2  |  2
```

Current output with the CTE recursion query

```
    Id | Parent_Id | Description | Account_Number | Year_of_entry| Amount|  X |  Y  
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1  | NULL      | V           | 001            | 2017         | 4     | 0  |  0  
    2  |  1        | W           | 002            | 2017         | 2     | 1  |  1
    5  |  1        | Z           | 005            | 2017         | 2     | 0  |  0
    6  |  5        | T           | 006            | 2017         | 2     | 1  |  1
    1  | NULL      | V           | 001            | 2016         | 8     | 0  |  0  
    2  |  1        | W           | 002            | 2016         | 4     | 2  |  2
    5  |  1        | Z           | 005            | 2016         | 4     | 2  |  2
```

Current output with @Daniel code

```
    Id | Parent_Id | Description | Account_Number | Year_of_entry| Amount|  X |  Y  
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2  |  1        | W           | 002            | 2017         | 2     | 1  |  1
    6  |  5        | T           | 006            | 2017         | 2     | 1  |  1
    2  |  1        | W           | 002            | 2016         | 4     | 2  |  2
    5  |  1        | Z           | 005            | 2016         | 4     | 2  |  2
```

I have used isnull to convert to 0

EDIT : Thanks for the Help.
I ended up using 2 recursive CTEs to resolve this.
The first to get the X and Y values to the Parent.
The Second to pass all the totals up the tree to the root.

Thanks again for the assistance.
Regards
MJK

Comment: Parent/Child... i think you actually want a Recursive CTE.

Comment: Thanks, MyTest is a recursive CTE. That part is working fine.

Comment: I think you want to do this logic in the recursive CTE, not in a subsequent SELECT, is my point. Create, in your Recursive CTE, an "X" and "Y" column, then as you are building out the data set in the recursive term (the bit below the UNION) test to see if you are on an 'X' or a 'Y' and slate it it into the appropriate column.

Comment: Thanks, Let me see if I can figure out how to code what you are describing

Comment: Hi @JNevill, I have added the values to the X and Y column in the recursive CTE. How would I go about adding those particular child entries into their parent X and Y columns?

Comment: Can you provide the query for parent cte?

Comment: I don't know what your source data looks like, or your Recursive CTE so it's hard to guide here. I would do a case statement though to test if it's an 'X' and then shove whatever value is in that particular column. then when you select from your recursive CTE you can ignore 'X' and 'Y' `Description` in your WHERE clause. You may have to get a little fancy about how you select from the results. (it probably won't be pretty).

Comment: @JNevill Updated the question to show the recursive CTE query.

Comment: @JNevill thanks for the tip on the recursive CTE. I took the long way but got to the solution.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear you solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional logic with aggregation to create your x and y columns:

```
select a.Id,  a.Parent_Id, a.Description, a.Account_Number,  a.Year_of_Entry, a.Amount, 
    max(case when b.description in ('x','y') 
    then null else b.amount end) amount, sum(case when b.description='x' then b.amount else null end) X, 
sum(case when b.description='y' then b.amount else null end) y  from yourtable a 
      join yourtable b on (a.id=b.parent_id or a.parent_id is null) and a.Year_of_Entry=b.Year_of_Entry
    where b. description in ('x','y')
    group by a.Id, a.Parent_Id, a.Description, a.Account_Number,  a.Year_of_Entry, a.Amount
    order by a.Year_of_Entry desc, a.parent_id
```

Comment: Thanks, How would I go about inserting the values in the X and Y columns from the child to the parent row? And not have those child rows show in the results.

Comment: Not following you exactly.  Please show what exactly you are missing from the solution above.

Comment: If you look at the question, there is a particular output that I am trying to achieve. Where the X and Y values transfer up to the parent from the child and the child id no longer shows in the output.

Comment: Do you mean keeping the amount field where the descriptions are not x and y? If so, please see updated code. Also I rolled it up to the ParentID level and removed accountnumber.  You can join the new data set back to the original (where description not in ('x','y')) if you  want to pull id and accountnumber back into the final query.

Comment: Thanks, I have used your code to get to a certain point.I can now group the parent that has the child X and Y values with the child values for X and Y. I am still unable to propagate the X and Y values further up. As per the required output in the Question, I am able to get ID 2 and 5 to have all the values in the amount,X,Y columns, however ID 1 shows as amount, null, null. It looks like I would need a reverse recursive CTE to propogate the X and Y values UP

Comment: Oh ok I see now.  Please see updated code above.  I tested it and it now matches your expected output.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. With your updated code, it seems to leave out the parents that do not have X and Y as children. Seems the issue I am having is with creating the X and Y columns as those do not seem to propagate upwards.

Comment: Can you please provide a new sample output then?  I coded it to match your sample output exactly.

Comment: Hi, The output is correct. The only difference to my live data is that there are other levels in the tree between the ones that have  X and Y as children. With your current code I am only seeing the parents that have X and Y directly as children. I did try the CTE code as well, with that code I end up with the parent which has X and Y children with its correct values, but the X and Y values there do not propagate up as well. I think it would have been easier to chat, but unfortunately I do not have the rep as yet.

Comment: So can you add one of those examples to your sample input and show the output?

Comment: Hi, I updated the question to show what is happening.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the assistance. I ended up using 2 recursive CTEs to get it working properly on the live data.